# Magento 2 configurable product Dropdown sort options

Tags: sorting, magento2, configurable

I want to ask how I can sort options in dropdown on magento 2 configurable product
I add products with Import csv file.

example:
First option is SIZE, second is COLOR
How I can sort options to make first COLOR, second SIZE. I use Import csv for add products.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDFA2.png)